# Remove read-only attribute using Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that copies some files and then removes their "read-only" attribute.

Using windows 8.1.

My file looks something like this:

```
@echo off 
set s1=copy successful
set s2=remove read only successful
set timer=2

XCOPY C:\my_dir_1\my_dir_2 C:\my_dir_2 /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y 
echo %s1%
timeout /T %timer%
attrib -r C:\my_dir_2 /s /d
echo %s2%
timeout /T %timer%
```

The copy is working fine and when I execute this, I see cmd prompt with all the files while they are being copied. The timers are also working as expected, but the remove read only is not. The prompt goes right to the 2nd timer part. I used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/653951/how-to-remove-read-only-attribute-recursively-on-windows-7) link as a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
attrib -r C:\my_dir_2 /s /d
```

sets the attribute for the folder. You want to set it for the files, so:

```
attrib -r C:\my_dir_2\* /s /d
```

Comment: I add * and it works on a little test dir I'm using, but I don't see any lines of execution in the prompt - is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

I created this batch file to do this.  Basically this batch file will clear read only attributes in the directory its in or the directory its in and all lower directories.  Hope someone finds a use for it.  Excuse any code that may seem "poor" as I am just starting to learn batch files myself.

```
@ECHO off
:begin
ECHO Would you like to only remove read only attributes
ECHO from this director or from all the sub directores as
ECHO well?
ECHO.
ECHO [A] This directory only
ECHO [B] All directories - cascading
ECHO [C] Cancel
SET /P actionChoice="Option(A,B,C): "
ECHO.
IF "%actionChoice%" == "A" GOTO A
IF "%actionChoice%" == "B" GOTO B
IF "%actionChoice%" == "C" GOTO C
GOTO badChoice

:A
CLS
ECHO Are you sure you want to remove all read-only
ECHO attributes from this directory only?
ECHO.
ECHO Directory:
ECHO.
ECHO %CD%
ECHO.
SET /P continueChoice="Continue? (Y, N): "
IF "%continueChoice%" == "N" GOTO abort
ECHO Removing Read Only Attributes From Local Directory...
SET currectDirectory=%CD%
ECHO Current directory is: %currectDirectory%
FOR %%G IN (%currectDirectory%\*) DO (
ECHO %%G
ATTRIB -R "%%G"
)
GOTO end

:B
CLS
ECHO Are you sure you want to remove all read-only
ECHO attributes from this directory and all sub-directories?
ECHO.
ECHO Directory:
ECHO.
ECHO %CD%
ECHO.
SET /P continueChoice="Continue? (Y, N): "
IF "%continueChoice%" == "N" GOTO abort
ECHO Removing Read Only Attributes Cascading...
FOR /R %%f IN (*) DO (
ECHO %%f
ATTRIB -R "%%f"
)
GOTO end

:C
CLS
ECHO Cancel: no files have been changed
GOTO end

:badChoice
CLS
ECHO Unknown Option
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
GOTO begin

:abort
CLS
ECHO No files have been changed
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
GOTO begin

:end
ECHO Read only attributes removed
PAUSE
```